# AWS certificate upload error: A client error (KeyPairMismatch) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, certificate

I get this error while trying to upload my certificates:

> A client error (KeyPairMismatch) occurred when calling the
>   UploadServerCertificate     operation: The private key did not match
>   the public key provided. Please verify the key     material and try
>   again.

I have followed all of the instructions on how to create and upload server certificates in the link here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/InstallCert.html

I have also received the following certificates through email:

- as PKCS#7 Base64 encoded
- as PKCS#7 Bin encoded
- as X509, Base64 encoded
- as X509 Certificate only, Base64 encoded
- as X509 Intermediates/root only, Base64 encoded
- as X509 Intermediates/root only Reverse, Base64 encoded

and I have laid out the upload code like this:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name my_cert_edu
    --certificate-body file://my_cert_edu.pem --private-key file://MYtesting.pem
    --certificate-chain file://my_cert_edu_interm.pem
```

Comment: The reason I was getting this error was because I was inputting the private key that I needed to access Putty with rather than the one I had generated from the following command: openssl genrsa 2048 > private-key.pem